# Minimising the result of multiple equations

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

Say we have the equations
$$2b=a$$ 
$$3c=a$$
$$4d=a$$
$$a\neq b\neq c\neq d$$
How can these be solved to find the smallest possible integer value of $a$ with all the other unknowns as integers? Is there a general way to find this if the list of equations continues with each expression on the L.H.S. increasing by one in both coefficient and letter of the alphabet (i.e. the next equation involved is $5e=a$, the next $6f=a$, so on and so forth) while each variable remains unequal to any other?

By inspection, I noticed one possible solution is $b=12$, $c=8$, and $d=6$ for $a=24$. I then noticed these are all divisible by $2$ so a more optimal solution is $a=12$, which I think (judging by the values for the other variables) is the smallest integer value it can take given the conditions. I don't think a method of inspection would be feasible if the collection of equations extended much further however, so was wondering if there's a better method for this.

Comment: Note that $b,c,d$ are automatically different and all strictly smaller than $a$ so the last condition is superfluous (and automatic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ must be the least common multiple of $2$, $3$ and $4$, i.e. $12$. This is by definition the answer for this special case.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's much more simple than I was thinking. But how do I find the LCM for the system as more and more equations are involved?

Comment: @Nemon27 You just find the LCM of every given number included.

Comment: @Peter Is there a method to do this? I'm familiar with a method to find the LCM of several numbers through inspection but how could this be done for a very large amount of equations?

Comment: Use the fact that $$\text{lcm}{(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)}=\text{lcm}{(a_0,\text{lcm}{(a_1,\dots,\text{lcm}{(a_{n-1},a_n)})})}$$

Comment: @Nemon27 you do it per pair: for 2,3,4 we first do 2 and 3: which have gcd 1 so lcm equal to 6, and then 6 and 4 have gcd 2, so lcm $6\times 4 / 2 = 12$ and you're done. You replace 2 numbers by their lcm and proceed.

Comment: @Nemon27 The gcd is computed by Euclid's algorithm for larger numbers and $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$. Very efficient.